# How to replace content area with an iframe when a button is clicked, via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a content area in which I want to display certain text when the page loads and the same text when a button is clicked (biography). When a different button is clicked (AFT), I want the text in the content area to be replaced with the content of a URL via an iframe.

I have managed to get the right text to display when the page loads, but when I click the 'AFT' button the text is replaced with "[object HTMLIFrameElement]" instead of displaying the iframe. Does anyone know whats going wrong?

HTML code:

```
    <div id="content" > 
    <script src="myJS.js"></script>
    <script> displayBiography(); </script>

    <iframe src="cwExample.pdf" name="iframe" id="iframe1"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="leftBar"> 
    <br><br>
    <button class="button" type="button" onclick="displayBiography();"> 
    Biography </button>
    <h3> Samples of Work </h3>
    <button class="button" type="button" onclick="toShow();" 
    target="#iframe1"> AFT </button>
```

JS Code:

```
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    var biography = "<p> Text here </p>"
    ;

    function displayBiography() {
        "use strict";
        content.innerHTML = biography;
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1');
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
    }


    function toShow() {
        var iframe1 = document.getElementById('iframe1');
        content.innerHTML = iframe1
        biography.style.display = 'none';
        iframe1.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

Comment: you can use jquery API and `.replaceWith()` function

Comment: this is a link for this function tutorial : 
http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions, depending on what your future aim could be. But in general, using an iFrame is not recommended at all.

## Hard coded text

If the text is static and doesn't need to be changed after coding, you can simply set the text with JS, without jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function() {
  showBio();

  // add event listeners to the buttons
}

function showBio() {
    var bio = "blabla";
    setContent(bio);
}

function showSmthElse() {
    var txt = "other blabla";
    setContent(txt);
}

function setContent(newContent) {
    var div = document.getElementById("content");
    if( div != null ) {
        div.innerHTML = '';
        div.insertAdjacentHTML = content;
    }
}
```

## Load text from database

If you want to change the text, give others the opportunity to change it or want to save multiple bios, think about storing them in a database on your server (if this is possible with your structure). In this case you should think about using AJAX. It's a technique to load data from a server without refreshing the page. There are a lot of tutorials on the web and many questions are already answered here. It's really not that difficult :)